# How to get the name of the current file in Swift?

Tags: swift

I need to get the current filename in Swift programatically.

Is it possible? Is there any hack that can be used to do the same?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can simply use [`#file` macro](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/file()) to get the name of the current file.
You can

Eg. just try compiling the following file
Swift 3:

```
println(#file)
```

Swift 2 or older:

```
println(__FILE__)
```

Comment: It should be `print` for both, not `println`.

Comment: Note: `#file` will give the entire path on your local machine, not just the file name. It will be improved in future versions, for now it's better to use `#fileID`.

Answer (score 2):

This answer should be updated, instead of using `__FILE__` you should now use `#file`.

Comment: Thanks! Updated :)

Answer (score 0):

### Edit

In newer versions of Swift the answer below won't work any more. (I believe the old answer was for Swift 1 or Swift 2.)

You want:

```
let sourceFile = #file
print(sourceFile)
```

---

The out-of-date answer for Swift 1/Swift 2:

And if you want it in a variable, you should be able to use

```
let sourcefile = "\(__file__)"
```

Comment: That does not compile, perhaps you meant `let sourcefile = "\(__FILE__)"
` ? – But you don't need string interpolation, `let sourcefile = __FILE__` would work as well.

Comment: Um, I had the same thing you show as a correction. In any case `__file__` is no longer supported. I updated my answer to use the new syntax.